# Is it possible to access the Database Data inside Forms? Using QuerySet inside a Django Form (if possible)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to make a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` from the data present in DB. This data in DB is related to user using a `ForeignKey`. I think I can access the data of a particular user using `data=user.ModelName_set.all()`

How can I make a `CheckBoxSelectMultiple` Form from this Data and save the result in different Model by connecting it to the same User?